# Does the threading option work with Lame in FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I currently have this:

```
        "ffmpeg",
        "-http_proxy", RandomProxyAddress(),
        "-i", vi.GetUrl(),
        "-acodec", "libmp3lame",
        "-metadata", fmt.Sprintf(`title=%s`, vi.GetTitle()),
        "-threads", "2",
        "-f", "mp3",
        "-")
```

Since Lame is a single thread, does putting in the `-threads` do anything at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For libmp3lame specifically, no.

```
$ ffmpeg -h encoder=libmp3lame
…
Threading capabilities: none
```

If any video is being encoded, and that encoder supports threading, then the `-threads` option may apply to that encoder.